# Translate: “If God Is For Me.”

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin

If God is for us, who can be against us?” - Romans 8:31

Looking to translate, “If God is for me.” from English to Latin.

Answer (score 2):

In the Latin Vulgate, that text reads, "si Deus **pro nobis** quis contra nos".

In order to change "us" to "me", we simply need to replace "nobis" with "me".

Therefore: Si deus pro me

Comment: *we simply need to replace "nobis" with "me"* – we don't even strictly need to ;-)